# Using VBA to check the details of my SQL query

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have been on Google, and have been searching for a while now. I am still coming up with nil. 
Is there a way to use VBA to check an SQL connection for it's details? i.e. what column the data came from and what was the source of that data.
We have multiple machines in the factory, each with their own data. I need to get this data and check machine A's data against B, C, and D.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you rephrase your question and share with us any attempt that you made programming wise, then...there could be some way this community could help you. :)

Comment: I hope so, I'm really at a loss right now. My biggest problem is that after searching, I still don't have a starting place. I just need a website, function (not looking for code handouts), or data property to point me in the right direction and I should be able to handle the rest from there.

Comment: Have you tried something like `thisworkbook.Connections.Item(1).OLEDBConnection.SourceDataFile`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thanks for that starting point. With that I was able to find the `.CommandText` property. Which is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much.